# Algorithm to find the narrowest intervals, m of which will cover a set of numbers

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

Let's say you have a list of **n** numbers. You are allowed to choose **m** integers (lets call the integer **a**). For each integer **a**, delete every number that is within the inclusive range [**a - x, a + x**], where **x** is a number. What is the minimum value of  **x** that can get the list cleared?

For example, if your list of numbers was

1 3 8 10 18 20 25

and m = 2, the answer would be x = 5.

You could pick the two integers 5 and 20. This would clear the list because it deletes every number in between [5-5, 5+5] and [20-5, 20+5].

How would I solve this? I think the solution may be related to dynamic programming. I do not want a brute force method solution.

Code would be really helpful, preferably in Java or C++ or C.

Comment: Have you tried anything thus far?

Comment: I'm slightly confused about the requirement. The m integers don't need to be from the list (e.g. the integer 5 from the example) and when you choose them, you can act as an adversary - trying to find the worst m integers. So the minimum value of x must be large enough to cope with the worst case whichever m integers you choose. But since there's no constraint on the m integers, why in the example didn't you choose e.g. -50,000,000,000,000,000 and +50,000,000,000,000,000, significantly increasing the needed x value?

Comment: Or is the "adversary" bit wrong? Is the choice of m integers co-operative - the best selection possible to solve the problems?

Comment: Binary search forvx, use the classic greedy covering algo to verify a guess

Comment: @BobBilly could you check my answer?

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera Yeah hold on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recursive solution:

First, you need an estimation, you can split in m groups, then estimated(x) must be ~ (greather - lower element) / 2*m. the estimated(x) could be a solution. If there is a better solution, It has lower x than extimated(x) in all groups! and You can check it with the first group and then repeat recursively. The problem is decreasing until you have only a group: the last one, You know if your new solution is better or not, If there'is better, you can use it to discard another worse solution.

```
private static int estimate(int[] n, int m, int begin, int end) {
    return (((n[end - 1] - n[begin]) / m) + 1 )/2;
}

private static int calculate(int[] n, int m, int begin, int end, int estimatedX){
    if (m == 1){
        return estimate(n, 1, begin, end);
    } else {
        int bestX = estimatedX;
        for (int i = begin + 1; i <= end + 1 - m; i++) {
            // It split the problem:
            int firstGroupX = estimate(n, 1, begin, i);
            if (firstGroupX < bestX){
                bestX = Math.min(bestX, Math.max(firstGroupX, calculate(n, m-1, i, end, bestX)));
            } else {
                i = end;
            }
        }
        return bestX;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] n = {1, 3, 8, 10, 18, 20, 25};
    int m = 2;
    Arrays.sort(n);
    System.out.println(calculate(n, m, 0, n.length, estimate(n, m, 0, n.length)));
}
```

**EDIT:**

Long numbers version: Main idea, It search for "islands" of distances and split the problem into different islands. like divide and conquer, It distribute 'm' into islands.

```
private static long estimate(long[] n, long m, int begin, int end) {
    return (((n[end - 1] - n[begin]) / m) + 1) / 2;
}

private static long calculate(long[] n, long m, int begin, int end, long estimatedX) {
    if (m == 1) {
        return estimate(n, 1, begin, end);
    } else {
        long bestX = estimatedX;
        for (int i = begin + 1; i <= end + 1 - m; i++) {
            long firstGroupX = estimate(n, 1, begin, i);
            if (firstGroupX < bestX) {
                bestX = Math.min(bestX, Math.max(firstGroupX, calculate(n, m - 1, i, end, bestX)));
            } else {
                i = end;
            }
        }
        return bestX;
    }
}

private static long solver(long[] n, long m,  int begin, int end) {
    long estimate = estimate(n, m, begin, end);
    PriorityQueue<long[]> islands = new PriorityQueue<>((p0, p1) -> Long.compare(p1[0], p0[0]));
    int islandBegin = begin;
    for (int i = islandBegin; i < end -1; i++) {
        if (n[i + 1] - n[i] > estimate) {
            long estimatedIsland = estimate(n, 1, islandBegin, i+1);
            islands.add(new long[]{estimatedIsland, islandBegin, i, 1});
            islandBegin = i+1;
        }
    }
    long estimatedIsland = estimate(n, 1, islandBegin, end);
    islands.add(new long[]{estimatedIsland, islandBegin, end, 1});
    long result;
    if (islands.isEmpty() || m < islands.size()) {
        result = calculate(n, m, begin, end, estimate);
    } else {    
        long mFree = m - islands.size();
        while (mFree > 0) {
            long[] island = islands.poll();
            island[3]++;
            island[0] = solver(n, island[3], (int) island[1], (int) island[2]);
            islands.add(island);
            mFree--;
        }
        result = islands.poll()[0];
    }
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    long[] n = new long[63];
    for (int i = 1; i < n.length; i++) {
        n[i] = 2*n[i-1]+1;
    }
    long m = 32;
    Arrays.sort(n);
    System.out.println(solver(n, m, 0, n.length));
}
```

Comment: It works for the example I gave, but doesn't work on the teacher's longer examples (There are thousands of numbers in the list). They are too long to copy/paste here.

Any idea why this doesn't work sometimes? I'm trying my best to debug this. 

This isn't due this week, but it would be nice if you could help me asap

Comment: @BobBilly Edited: for long numbers.

Answer (score 4):

### Hints

Suppose you had the list

```
1 3 8 10 18 20 25
```

and wanted to find how many groups would be needed to cover the set if x was equal to 2.

You could solve this in a greedy way by choosing the first integer to be 1+x (1 is the smallest number in the list).  This would cover all elements up to 1+x+x=5.  Then simply repeat this process until all numbers are covered.

So in this case, the next uncovered number is 8, so we would choose 8+x=10 and cover all numbers up to 10+x=12 in the second group.

Similarly, the third group would cover [18,24] and the fourth group would cover [25,29].

This value of x needed 4 groups.  This is too many, so we need to increase x and try again.

You can use bisection to identify the smallest value of x that does cover all the numbers in m groups.

Answer (score 2):

An effective algorithm can be(assuming list is sorted) ->

1. We can think of list as groups of 'm' integers.
2. Now for each group calculate 'last_element - first_element+1', and store maximum of this value in a variable say, 'ans'.
3. Now the value of 'x' is 'ans/2'.

I hope its pretty clear how this algorithm works.

Comment: I'm thinking of the list 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ... 100. Let m=2. How does the algorithm work for this example?

Comment: ok. now two groups are -> [1,2,...50] and [51,52,....100], first half 50-1=49 and for second 100-51=49 , maximumm of these=49 so x=49/2...but i think we should increment 'ans' to 'ans'+1 so that ans=25.. or use 'ceil' function.. now 25-25,25+25, 75-25, 75+25.. whole list is clear.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's similarly problem of clusterization. For example You may use k-means clustering algorithm: do partitions of initial list on m classes and for x get maximum size divided by two of obtained classes.

Answer (score 0):

1)  You should look into BEST CASE, AVERAGE CASE and WORST CASE complexities with regards to TIME and SPACE complexities of algorithms.

2)  I think David Pérez Cabrera has the right idea.  Let's assume average case (as in the following pseudo code)

3)  Let the list of integers be denoted by l

```
    keepGoing = true
    min_x = ceiling(l[size-1]-l[0])/(2m)

    while(keepGoing)
    {
        l2 = l.copy
        min_x = min_x-1
        mcounter = 1

        while(mcounter <= m)
        {
            firstElement = l2[0]
//  This while condition will likely result in an ArrayOutOfBoundsException
//  It's easy to fix this.

            while(l2[0] <= firstElement+2*min_x)
            {   remove(l2[0])   }
            mcounter = mcounter+1
        }
        if(l2.size>0)
            keepGoing = false
    }
    return min_x+1
```

4)  Consider

```
l = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, m=2 (gives x=2)
l = {1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000}, m=2
l = {1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000}, m=3
```